# Jenkins: "Execute system groovy script" in a pipeline step (SCM committed)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Is there a way to use the Jenkins "Execute system groovy script" step from a pipeline file which is SCM commited ?

If yes, how would I access the predefined variables (like build) in it ?

If no, would I be able to replicate the functionality otherwise, using for example the Shared Library Plugin ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put groovy code in a pipeline in a (always-source-controlled) Jenkinsfile, like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {
        script {

          // i used a script block because you can jam arbitrary groovy in here
          // without being constrained by the declarative Jenkinsfile DSL
          def awesomeVar = 'so_true'
          print "look at this: ${awesomeVar}"

          // accessing a predefined variable:
          echo "currentBuild.number: ${currentBuild.number}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Produces console log:

```
[Pipeline] echo
look at this: so_true
[Pipeline] echo
currentBuild.number: 84
```

Click on the "Pipeline Syntax" link in the left navigation of any of pipeline job to get a bunch of examples of things you can access in the "Global Variables Reference."

Comment: I don't think script put this way is executed on the master, but rather is constrained by the sandbox mode of jenkins ? I'm super interested in the system part of "Execute system groovy script" :-D

Comment: it is executed on the master, and it is constrained by the sandbox mode of jenkins, which can be overridden on a case by case basic per the approach described at https://medium.com/dronzebot/jenkins-groovy-script-approval-eff569f597f6.

Comment: Ok, my bad, great then :)

Comment: @burnettk, would it work if I have imports in my groovy code?